# How Do I Force an iOS App Into Resign Active?

Tags: ios, background, quit

I've been looking all over for this, and have a nasty feeling the answer is "You can't."

I have an app that establishes a wireless connection to a device as soon as it becomes active. It's a super-simple, one-window app that should only show a screen when connected.

I want to be able to push it into the background when it can't connect. I don't want to force-quit. I just want to do the equivalent of the "Home" button being pressed.

The alternative is to show a different background with a "not connected" message. What I would rather do, is display an error alert. When the alert is dismissed, the app retreats into the background. Bringing it to the foreground once again attempts the connection. Pushing it into the background while connected will break the connection.

Thinking about that, the latter is a better idea, anyway, but this did get me thinking. Is it possible to do the former? I don't want to deliberately crash an app (like throwing an uncaught exception).

Comment: Press the home button. ;)

Comment: :) However, I'd like to do it programatically. I expanded the question a bit. The whole idea is to KISS

Comment: The only way to make your app become inactive would be to launch another app. But there is no way to programmatically return to the Home screen.

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured that. Well, I'll splash up a "not connected" message. No big deal, but it would have been kinda cool to have it just fade back. I could have done a "Cheshire cat" fade...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the app continually retry to connect whilst it is in the foreground?

Comment: Might try that. Maybe a bit of A/B testing.